# Combine Jackson's @JsonGetter with Lombok's @Getter

Tags: java, jackson, lombok

I have some fields annotated with `@Getter/Setter`. Now I want to use `@JsonGetter/JsonSetter` on top of that. Can this be done or do I have to write out the methods to use `Jackson-annotations` on them?

```java
class C {
     @JsonGetter // Compile error
     @Getter
     private int count;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@JsonGetter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/1.9/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonGetter.html) is method level annotation, so you can only add this annotation for methods, Since `1.5` (deprecated since version 1.5) it is deprecated and recommended to use [@JsonProperty](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html)

```
@Target(value=METHOD)
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
@Deprecated
public @interface JsonGetter
```

> **Marker annotation that can be used to define a non-static, no-argument value-returning (non-void) method to be used as a "getter"** for a logical property, as an alternative to recommended JsonProperty annotation (which was introduced in version 1.1).